# Applet Viewing Issues

Tags: java, applet, classnotfoundexception

I'm new to Java and I'm having an issue viewing my Java applet in an HTML file.

My source:

- Package is `simplest`
- Java file is `Simplest.java`
- HTML file is `Simplest.html`

### Java Code

```
package simplest;

public class Simplest 
extends java.applet.Applet
{

@Override
public void paint(java.awt.Graphics gr)
{
gr.drawString("Seeing is believing",25,75);
gr.drawRect(0,0,299,199);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
}
}
```

### HTML

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML Test Page</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
An Applet that paints itself.
<hr>
<applet code="Simplest.class" width="300" height="200">
</applet>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `"and I'm having an issue viewing my java applet in an html file."` ... and that issue is? Please post any and all pertinent details.

Comment: its giving me a classnotfoundexception error

Comment: `ClassNotFoundException` almost always means you don't have the proper version of Java installed.  Try compiling at a lower compliance level or jar'ing the file up as suggested in my answer and using the `archive` property.

Answer (score 1):

If the page doesn't load either you have the wrong HTML tag (which is what this looks like), you don't have the proper version of the JRE (say you compiled in 1.6 but the user only has 1.5), or the browser doesn't have the necessary Java plugin (and/or is also the wrong version).  Java is backwards compatible, so it's usually a good idea to compile in the lowest necessary compliance level unless this is just for yourself.

The html code should look like this:

```
<applet code = 'simple.Simplest' 
archive = 'simple.jar'
width = 300
height = 200>
<-- no params for this applet -->
</applet>
```

Where you have jar'd up the project (or just the one package) into the file simple.jar.  Also, if this is local, then simple.jar has to be in the same directory where you opened the HTML file, otherwise it should be an absolute path.  If it's on the server, again, you need to specify the proper URL for where the jar is located (if it's in the same context as this page, then the above should be fine).

You might want to look through this Java Tutorials thread: [Deploying With the Applet Tag](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/html.html)

Comment: Nice answer.  :)  But IMO the ***best*** way to deploy a JWS app. or applet is to use the [Deployment Toolkit Script](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/depltoolkit_index.html).